# Необходимо получить размеченные твитты русского языка

Tags: mysql, csv

Необходимо получить в читаемом варианте положительные и отрицательные твиты вот отсюда:
http://study.mokoron.com/

при скачивании файла в csv вместо твитов нечитаемые символы. При попытке скачать файл в mysql создается колонка с одним пустым столбцом

Comment: Как же ответить на вопрос типа "я попытался что-то сделать, не получилось, попытался сделать по-другому, опять не получилось"? Попытайтесь сделать еще что-нибудь.

Comment: А "нечитаемые символы", это, часом, не банально UTF-8?

Comment: насколько я понимаю, utf-8 - это кириллица?

Comment: Да нет, UTF-8 — это всё, что угодно: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: тогда, не знаю.